# How to display Products By Category in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

Hi there I'm Beginner in React
I'm using React.js and trying to display Categories from public API and it showed up successfully in my app
Now I am trying to display the products for each category separately
So that if I click on a specific category, all the products for that category will appear on a separate page

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter,Routes,Route} from "react-router-dom";
import Categories from './components/Categories';
import Items from './components/Items';
function App() {


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" exact element={<Categories />}/>
          <Route path="/items" element={<Items />}/>
        </Routes>
        {/* <Items /> */}
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Categories.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import '../style/Categories/categories.css'
import axios from 'axios'
const Categories = () => {

    const [categories, setCategories] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        const getCategory = async () => {
            const res = await axios.get('https://api.publicapis.org/categories')
            setCategories(res.data.categories)
            console.log("res.data", res.data);
        }
        getCategory()
    }, [])
    return (
        <>
            <h1 style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>All Categories</h1>
            <div className="category__wrapper">
                {categories.map(category =>
                    <div key={Math.random()} className="category__item">
                        <h2><a href="#" >{category}</a></h2>
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Categories
```

**Items.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'
import '../style/Items/items.css'


const Items = () => {
    const [items, setItems] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        const getItems = async () => {
            const result = await axios.get('https://api.publicapis.org/entries')
            setItems(result.data.entries)
            console.log("result.entries", result.data.entries);
        }
        getItems()
    }, [])
    return (
        <div className="item__wrapper">
            {items.map((item) => (
                <div class="ui card" key={item.API}>
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="header">{item.API}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <p>{item.Description}</p>
                        <span>Category: {item.Category}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="extra content">
                        <button class="ui button">Show More</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Items
```

Comment: I guess you need to add a onClick handler to each category that you render. That handler should navigate to /items route and pass the id of the category you selected. Then the Items component should pass that id to the request for items and fetch only items for that specific category

Comment: Does you `item` have a `category` field? like `item.category` ? If it does you can filter based on the `category` selected by setting the item array again in a useEffect, whenever someone changes the category value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

logancodemaker's answer is almost corret, but a few things missing.

Basically you need to send the Category to the Items component to be able to filter by category.

1-) Items route must be updated in App.js to accept url parameter.

```
<Route path="/items/:category" element={<Items />}/>
```

2-) We use Link component from the react-router-dom package in the Categories.js to dynamically send the category url parameter.

```
<Link to={`/items/${category}`} >{category}</Link>
```

3-) In Items.js we are filtering the products by the given category name.

```
    import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
    
    const {category} = useParams(); 
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const getItems = async () => {
            const result = await axios.get('https://api.publicapis.org/entries');

            const allItems = result.data.entries;
            const categoryItems = allItems.filter(item => item.Category === category);
            setItems(categoryItems)
        }
        getItems()
    }, [category])
```

Comment: Great, I thought the category filter was done from the API

Answer (score 2):

In **App.js**

```
- <Route path="/items" element={<Items />}/>
+ <Route path="/items/:categoryId" element={<Items />}/>
```

**Categories.js**

```
+ import { Link } from "react-router-dom"

- <h2><a href="#" >{category}</a></h2>

+ <h2>
+   <Link to={`/items/${category.id}`}>{category}</Link>
+ </h2>
```

Items.js

```
const Items = () => {
+  const { categoryId } = useParams()

  const [items, setItems] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const getItems = async () => {
-      const result = await axios.get('https://api.publicapis.org/entries')
+      const result = await axios.get(`https://api.publicapis.org/entries/${categoryId}`)
      setItems(result.data.entries)
      console.log("result.entries", result.data.entries);
    }
    getItems()
  }, [])
```